# Get data from database based on search by name(Input field) in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have an issue with Laravel. I have a page where two fields are given; one is a select option in which two parameters are given (`name`, `PRN`). Below this, I have an input field and submit button.

When the user writes the name in the input field and searches. It should get data from that user on the next page in table format.

**receipt.blade.php**

```
<body> 
<div class="form_design">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 mx-auto">
        
            <h1 class="mt-0 text-center mb-4 text-white">Get Receipt</h1>
            <p style="text-align: left; margin-bottom: 0px !important;">
            <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard" class="btn btn-sm  px-5" id="submit-form" style="background-color: #c2d3c8;color: black;font-size: 14px;font-weight: 600;">Home</a>                    </p>   

            <div class="boxed_shadow">
            <h5><span class="question-label active">Search your transactions for Receipt</span></h4>  
                
                <form action="{{url('/')}}" id="submit_form" method="POST" >
                @csrf
                <div class="alert alert-danger" id="RegisterAlert" role="alert" style="display:none">Record not found.</div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="tran_type">
                    <option value="pg_res_txn_id">PRN</option>  
                    </select>
                </div><!-- /input-group -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label><span class="star_vld">*</span>Search Based On PRN</label>
                    <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="MainContent_TextBoxEmpId">     
                </div>
            <div class="form-group text-center">  
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm  px-5" id="MainContent_ButtonSearch" value="Search" style="background-color: #c2d3c8;font-size: 14px;font-weight: 600;">
            </form>
            <form id="receipt_list" method="POST" style="display:none" >
                <table id="rec_list" border='1' class="table">
                </table>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ReceiptController.php**

```
class ReceiptController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('receipt');
    }
}
```

Please give me the solution for this. If anyone wants more data, I can share it with you want to get data based on search and display it on the next page. Data should be from the database; my table name is 'form2s'.

I didn't get the result. I tried but did not get a result.
I have been working on Laravel for the last three months.

Comment: Form elements require a `name` attribute to be accessed serverside

Comment: How do you submit your form, is Javascript involved?

Comment: @brombeer SIR please explain more . i didn't get this

Comment: no sir javascript not involve

Comment: If you want to access a form element's value serverside/in PHP the element needs a `name` attribute

Comment: The PHP manual has a page on [Dealing with Forms](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) you might want to read

Comment: actually sir this a single page of a project , this page is use to get data from database for get PDF for the users

Comment: That's irrelevant right now. Your form has no submit button and your elements are missing the `name` attribute as mentioned. Fix that first, then, if you can actually access the data submitted by the form, deal with database access. And don't assume people's gender, someone might get offended

Comment: sir i didn't get the answer for this i use name attribute for this